# add new row in R based on a factor variable

Tags: r, function, conditional-statements

I have a data.frame with multiple entries per unique id. I need to determine which rows exceed a predefined time limit of 60 seconds. I have already attached a column that is populated with the term "toolong" to indicate the row I need to split the time column. I then want to create a new row directly below the row that has "toolong" and preserve all the same information as the "parent row" except to change the action column to "l" and the time column to the previous time - 60. The parent row will contain all the same information except the action column will be changed to "for" and the time to 60 secs. There are a total of 32 columns in the original database so preserving all the contents of the row other than action and time is necessary.

Example:

```
id <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2)
resting <- c("f","f","toolong","f","f","f","toolong","f")
action <- c("h","h","l","d","h","h","l","d")
time <- c(90,12,120,14,90,12,110,14)
other <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,5,4)
dat <- data.frame(cbind(id,resting,action,time,other))
```

How I would like it to look:

```
   id2 resting2 action2 time2 other2
1    1        f       h    90      1
2    1        f       h    12      2
3    1  toolong     for    60      3
4    1  toolong       l    60      3
5    1        f       d    14      4
6    2        f       h    90      5
7    1        f       h    12      6
8    2  toolong     for    60      5
9    2  toolong       l    50      5
10   2        f       d    14      4
```

Thanks, Tim

Comment: I have tried both of these answers and neither have worked to handle my problem as stated. Both give me duplicate rows but DWin's answer does not address the time issue and Neal's answer is also not giving the correct time for the rows. the "toolong" row needs to have 60 seconds with the remainder of the time being attributed to the next row. Any hints on how to make this happen?

Answer (score 2):

First, repeat the rows that are toolong...

```
R>rowID <- rep(1:8, times=as.factor(resting))        
R>dat2 <- dat[rowID,]
R>dat2
    id resting action time other
1    1       f      h   90     1
2    1       f      h   12     2
3    1 toolong      l  120     3
3.1  1 toolong      l  120     3
4    1       f      d   14     4
5    2       f      h   90     5
6    2       f      h   12     6
7    2 toolong      l  110     5
7.1  2 toolong      l  110     5
8    2       f      d   14     4
```

Then, for the duplicated ones, subtract of 60min per previous record...

```
R>dups <- unlist(tapply(duplicated(rowID), rowID,cumsum))
R>dat2$time <- dat2$time - 60*dups
R>dat2[dat2$resting == "toolong", "time"] <- pmin(60, dat2[dat2$resting == "toolong",     "time"] )
R>dat2
    id resting action time other
1    1       f      h   90     1
2    1       f      h   12     2
3    1 toolong      l   60     3
3.1  1 toolong      l   60     3
4    1       f      d   14     4
5    2       f      h   90     5
6    2       f      h   12     6
7    2 toolong      l   60     5
7.1  2 toolong      l   50     5
8    2       f      d   14     4
```

Answer (score 1):

```
dat2 <- rbind(dat, dat[ dat$resting=="toolong" , ])
dat2 <- dat2[order(rownames(dat2)), ]
dat2[duplicated(dat2), "action"] <- "l"
names(dat2) <- paste0(names(dat2), "2")
dat2
#-------
   id2 resting2 action2 time2 other2
1    1        f       h    90      1
2    1        f       h    12      2
3    1  toolong       l   120      3
31   1  toolong       l   120      3
4    1        f       d    14      4
5    2        f       h    90      5
6    2        f       h    12      6
7    2  toolong       l   110      5
71   2  toolong       l   110      5
8    2        f       d    14      4
```

The other way for constructing duplicate rownames to be used as a selection vector was with `mapply` and adding 1 to a logical vector. That may have some advantage as the periods in the rownames are a better "dupe" indicator.

```
 dat[ unlist(mapply( rep, rownames(dat), 1+(dat$resting=="toolong"))) , ]

    id resting action time other
1    1       f      h   90     1
2    1       f      h   12     2
3    1 toolong      l  120     3
3.1  1 toolong      l  120     3
4    1       f      d   14     4
5    2       f      h   90     5
6    2       f      h   12     6
7    2 toolong      l  110     5
7.1  2 toolong      l  110     5
8    2       f      d   14     4
```

Addressing the comment::modifications of the question:

```
dat2$action2 <- as.character(dat2$action2)
dat2[ dat2$resting2=="toolong" & !duplicated(dat2) , "action2"] <- "for"
dat2
   id2 resting2 action2 time2 other2
1    1        f       h    90      1
2    1        f       h    12      2
3    1  toolong     for   120      3
31   1  toolong       l   120      3
4    1        f       d    14      4
5    2        f       h    90      5
6    2        f       h    12      6
7    2  toolong     for   110      5
71   2  toolong       l   110      5
8    2        f       d    14      4
```

Comment: DWin - I also needed to change the original action from "l" to "for" and the original time from whatever it was to 60 and have the new time be the remainder (original time minus 60). Can this be incorporated into this code as well?

Comment: dat2[ dat2$action2=="toolong" & !duplicated(dat2) , "action2"] <- "for"`

Comment: DWin - Where do I add this code and how can I get the correct time for each of the "toolong" rows?

Comment: I assumed you would add the code after the construction and modification of `dat2`, except I didn't test it and it generates an error related to the fact that "for" is a new level for that particular factor. Probably should convert "action2" to a character vector. Also it should have been `dat2$resting2=="toolong"`